# Using PHP + VoltDB together?

Tags: php, sql, rdbms, voltdb

Is there any way to use voltDB in a PHP application?

It definitely seems like it have a few advantages over other Databases out there!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Absolutely.

VoltDB has added a HTTP/JSON client interface to VoltDB which is available now for preview.  You can download/build from http://community.voltdb.com/getinvolved#svn

Also, a C++ client library (via same page under "Client Interfaces for Other Programming Languages") exists and will be used to create a native client library for PHP.  Join the community at http://community.voltdb.com to be updated.

Comment: No problem at all.  Since your reputation is high enough (>250) can you please create a tag for VoltDB?

Comment: Hi, i couldn't do that - "users with less than 1500 reputation can't create new tags. The tag 'voltdb' is new. Try using an existing tag instead. " :)

Answer (score 5):

The native PHP client library that @tmcallaghan alluded to is now under development.

You can download/build it here:

https://svn.voltdb.com/clientapi/php/trunk/

And here's an example of it in use:

https://source.voltdb.com/browse/ClientAPI/php/trunk/examples/helloworld.php?r=HEAD

Answer (score 3):

VoltDB developer here. Ning Shi just finished a really nice PHP extension that is a big improvement in performance and usability over the old PHP extension.

The old extension was SWIG wrapper around the C++ client library which was verbose because of C++'s weaker vararg and reflection support. The server also didn't support binding parameters as strings for you which meant the client had to know the signature of the procedure up front and the application had to provide it.

The new extension has no PHP code so it loads faster and it has a more idiomatic PHP interface that uses PHP arrays and doesn't require you to declare a procedure and its parameters before invoking it.

The new client is on the [download page](http://voltdb.com/products-services/downloads).